# Build my Flutter application for iOS platform

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I want to build my Flutter application for iOS platform.

1. I registered and purchase Apple developer account.
2. At developer.apple.com registered new certificate.

[image]

3. Opened in Xcode my project and want to build application.
4. At page Signing and Capabilities selected my team (my account). I looks pretty well from my point of view.

[image]

But when I'm trying to build my application I got error:

```
Signing for "Runner" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
```

What does it mean? What I have to do in order to build my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Runner' seems not to be your application name but maybe some Flutter library right?

Try to search for it in Targets (icon for Targets can be located a little bit above and on the left looking at the xcode screen you posted).

You can also search for it on the left pane in the Project Navigator. When you find it - select your team for signing, just like you did with your main app target.

EDIT:

I'm editing answer as the the problem was user did not select signing for other modes (as in comments below).

So the solution was:
on Signing can you select your team for another modes ('All', 'Release', 'Debug'). And also clean and rebuild your solution.

Comment: No, Runner is my application. I can see my app icon in the place where you described.

Comment: Oh ok, so still looking at your xcode screen - on Signing can you select your team for another modes ('All', 'Release', 'Debug'). And also clean and rebuild your solution

Comment: Thank you very much for you mention about another mode. I selected team in profile mode but does not create it in release mode. Now it works pretty well. Thanks again